# Flat map list without losing mapping?

Tags: python, dictionary, flatten

I have a existing dict that maps single values to lists.
I want to reverse this dictionary and map from every list entry on the original key.
The list entries are unique.

Given:

```
dict { 1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c'] }
```

Result:

```
dict { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2 }
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Keys are tuples with 3 integer values and values (list entries) are strings. For example: { (1, 1, 1): ['a', 'b', 'c'] }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an option

```
new_dict = {v: k for k, l in d.items() for v in l}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Comment: That is a straight forward solution. Thanks. What is the right keyword for this technique (so that I can further read up on this)?

Comment: list comprehension or dict comprehension

Comment: In particular, it's a nested dict comprehension because it uses `for` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to produce a tuple with the key-value pair, then, flatten the new list and pass to the built-in dictionary function:

```
d = { 1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c'] }
new_d = dict([c for h in [[(i, a) for i in b] for a, b in d.items()] for c in h])
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```